# Javascript sprite rotation animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, rotation, sprite

I'm trying to figure out how to create a rotating image effect using a sprite sheet in javascript. What I'm trying to do:

Two buttons:

Left button: Rotate 15 frames to the left. 
Right button: Rotate 15 frames to the right.

I realize that there are jquery plugins that would allow me to easily do this, but I want to try it from scratch. Beyond the general idea, I don't know where to proceed. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have all images inside one file, you might want to look into CSS sprites (background image positioning tricks), then animate the background image position change. I know you'd like to start from scratch, but this might help: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this [jsFiddle to see a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhumc/)

---

Based on your question, it sounds like you're trying to learn how to animate a sprite and not actually rotate a single image.  If so, here is how you would animate a sprite.  Note: this uses an image of a man running. In your question, you asked about a rotating image effect.  In either case, you are simply looking at different slice of a sprite and then animation is solely dependent on the sprite.  As long as your sprite displays a rotating image then the image will appear to rotate.

If you need a plugin to actually rotate an image, [see here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/).

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgWidth = 240;
var imgHeight = 296;
var ximages = 6;
var yimages = 5;
var currentRow = 0;
var currentColumn = 0;

function MoveSprite(dir) { 
    if (dir == "left") {
        currentColumn--;
        if (currentColumn < 0)
        {
            currentColumn = ximages -1;
            if (currentRow == 0) {
                currentRow = yimages - 1;
            }
            else {
                currentRow--;
            }
        }   
    }
    else {
        currentColumn++;
        if (currentColumn == ximages) {
            currentColumn = 0;
            if (currentRow == yimages - 1) {
                currentRow = 0;
            }
            else {
                currentRow++;
            }
        }
    }
    $("#txtRow").val(currentRow);
    $("#txtColumn").val(currentColumn);
    $("#spritesheet").css("backgroundPosition", -imgWidth * currentColumn + "px " + -imgHeight * currentRow + "px"); 
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="MoveSprite('left');return false;">Move Left</button><button onclick="MoveSprite('right');return false;">Move Right</button>
<div id="spritesheet"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
#spritesheet {
    height: 296px;
    width:240px;
    background-image:url('walking_spritesheet.png');
}
</style>
```

**Sample Sprite**  (1440x1480):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with MovieClip in flash, I made a library that gives you a similar interface in javascript. https://github.com/wolthers/SpriteClip.js

Answer (score 0):

you could try

- css3 (rotation) ex : http://antimatter15.com/misc/rotatedgooglecss3.html
- canvas (javascript) ex : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas
- svg (dom or other libs) ex : http://www.svgbasics.com/rotate.html , http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html